# How to make Vidalia work with Tor and Privoxy?

Tags: proxy, tor

I installed Vidalia and Privoxy. When I start Vidalia, I get connected to the Tor network.

But my IP address wont change with both browsers Opera and Chrome. My settings in proxy are set to local host 8118.

This used to work, but now the IP address wont change.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did sagarchalise's suggestion work?

Comment: Try port 9050 instead, or try Torbutton.

Comment: If you are using the tor network for web browsing only, I recommend trying out the Tor Browser Bundle.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use tor you need to have configuration set for privoxy. Tor itself recommends polipo to privoxy. Yet configuration for both polipo and privoxy is attached in official tor documentation.

https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-unix.html.en#polipo

I havenot used vidalia but basically you need to restart tor with `sudo /etc/init.d/tor restart` after you setup configuration and setup your applications.